# Why is my previously uploaded profile picture still saved?

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I used to have an uploaded photo as my profile picture (many months ago now). When I went into edit profile and hit `Change picture`, I noticed my previously uploaded photo was still saved. I figure if I remove my profile picture, it should be gone "permanently".

**Why is it still saved on my account and on SE's imgur?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, we save one most recent image. Usually that's the image that you're currently using. You switched from that image to your Gravatar but that doesn't mean that we get rid of your image. It's considered a feature that we retain one image and allow you to swap to your Gravatar.

If you really want us to lose that image, you'll need to upload a new one. It doesn't have to be anything in particular and you'll be able to swap back to your Gravatar right away.

Comment: So my previous uploaded one will be removed permanently from SE's imgur after I upload a new one?

Comment: Let me check - I don't think we generally remove images from imgur. We can - we have a way to do that - but it's generally manual. I'll update when I have more info.